# Why can I only send iMessage and not SMS for some contacts?

Tags: iphone, messages, contacts, sms

For most contacts, if iMessage is not available (no internet, iMessage disabled in settings, etc), I am able to send a SMS txt message instead.

But I have a couple contacts that will not attempt an SMS message. The gray placeholder text in the text input box is "iMessage" instead of "Text Message" and when attempting to send the message, the arrow button is blue and not green. When pressing the button it says you need to enable iMessage.

The contacts are configured with an actual mobile phone number and sms messaging works for other contacts configured in the same way.

The contacts have sms enabled on their phones and they are not blocking me or anything like that. I have even verified the settings on one of their phones as part of trying to figure this out.

When iMessage is enabled, sending iMessages to them works fine.

Things I have tried:

- Reset network settings
- Delete entire message history and a contact having the problem
- Disable iMessage, including disabling iMessage on both my phone and one of the contacts' phones at the same time to test if that was an issue
- Turn off both wifi and mobile data
- Log out of my apple id for the messages app
- Reboot phone at various points in trying things, including forced restart (vol up, vol down, hold power until restarts)
- Restart messages app at various points in trying things

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have they correct phone number in your contacts

Comment: yes, double checked that and even re-entered it and also tried with the country code and without

Comment: did you try to take them off the iMessage list

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: they may have SMS turned off on their side

Comment: One of them is my wife's and she has sms turned on and can text message me just fine. Although she has the same problem when sending to her mother.

Comment: I also figured out that if I let the message just sit there, it will eventually fail (takes about 20 minutes) and then I have the option to try it as a text message and that works. Turn data back on and it switches back to iMessage sending and that works fine, turn data off and it is stuck on iMessage again and I have to wait for it to fail 20 minutes later to be able to do SMS.